# Why does adding overflow: hidden make the child element's margin work?

Tags: html, css, overflow, margin, margins

When I add an element like `h1` with `margin: 30px 0;`, the margin goes outside the container!

I faced this problem many times before, and I solved it by using `overflow: hidden`

I want to figure out what's the problem and why this solution works?

Find a JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/zv6c2c2d/

```css
.container {
  background: #ccc;
}
.container.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.secTitle {
  margin: 30px 0;
}
code {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- secTitle margin goes outside the container -->
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="secTitle">Container without <code>overflow: hidden</code></h1>
</div>

<!-- works fine here -->
<div class="container overflow">
  <h1 class="secTitle">Container with <code>overflow: hidden</code></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use padding instead? That's what it is designed for!

Comment: @jbutler483 I can use many other ways, but I want to figure out why it's happening.

Comment: margin is meant to be outside of the element.

Answer (score 6):

#### Why is this occurring?

In the first example, the [margin(s) are collapsed](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) within the parent element.

For some context, here is the relevant documentation on collapsing margins:

> [**Box Model 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> When two or more margins collapse, the resulting margin width is the maximum of the collapsing margins' widths. In the case of negative margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the negative adjoining margins is deducted from the maximum of the positive adjoining margins. If there are no positive margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the adjoining margins is deducted from zero.

There are specific rules that will prevent the margins from collapsing.

One of the rules specified is:

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children. [**[link]**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

In your case, the element has an `overflow` value other than the default, `visible`, since it is set to `hidden`. Thus, the margins do not collapse and they are contained within the element.

For more workarounds, check out [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Answer (score -1):

```
.container.overflow
```

It should be

```
.container .overflow
```

```css
.container {
    background: #ccc;
}

.container .overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.secTitle {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

code {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- secTitle margin goes outside the container -->
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="secTitle">
        Container without 
        <code>overflow: hidden</code>
    </h1>
</div>

<!-- works fine here -->
<div class="container overflow">
    <h1 class="secTitle">
        Container with 
        <code>overflow: hidden</code>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why ? Because margins are meant to be outside the element and here doesn't consider the `h1` margins. By default, `overflow` is at visible and renders outside the `h1` container. It's quite hard to explain but I tried ! Hope I helped.

Comment: @LeoAref I added an answer explaining why and referenced the official documentation.