# Ghost Top Body Margin With Floated Divs

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I wrote the following code and tried placing three left floated divs in a father containing div. For some reason, the body tag seems to have a ghost top margin, which is a property not defined in my code. However, if I remove the margin-bottom property of the containing div or apply a clearfix style to it, the top margin is gone. What causes the ghost top margin and how to fix it? Thx!

Check the screenshots below:

- Original code:

  [image]
- `Margin-bottom` removed:

  [image]

  - Clearfix style applied:

  [image]

**This the original code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                font: 16px/2 Tohoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif, 'Microsoft YaHei';
                background: #ccc;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .clear-fix:after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                clear: both;
            }

            #wrap {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 1000px;
                min-height: 800px;
                background: #fff;
            }

            #header {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .first, .second, .third {
                float: left;
                padding: 20px;
                min-height: 100px;
            }

            .first {
                background: gray;
            }

            .second {
                background: blue;
            }

            .third {
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <title>
            Another Web Page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="first">This is the first floating division</div>
                <div class="second">This is the second floating division</div>
                <div class="third">This is the third floating division</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Original code preview:**http://jsfiddle.net/qv8ph0gw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The explanation:

There are a few things occurring here.

When elements are absolutely positioned **or** floated (as in your case), they are removed from the normal flow of the document. Here is relevant documentation confirming this:

> [**9 Visual formatting model - 9.5 Floats**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)
>
> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box of the float.

In your case, the children elements of the `#header` element are floated. Since *all* of the children elements are floated, the `#header` element essentially collapses upon it self since it doesn't have any dimensions.

Here is a visual example. As you can see, the parent, `#header` element, has a height of `0`:

[image: collapsed]

Since the element has a height of `0`, the `margin-bottom` essentially acts as a `margin-top`, and the [margin collapses](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) with the `body` element.

I just answered a question about [collapsing margins here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731893/why-does-adding-overflow-hidden-make-the-child-elements-margin-work/33818240#33818240), but here is the relevant documentation:

> [**Box Model 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

#### Possible solutions/workarounds:

As you noted, the problem is resolved my adding a clearfix to the `#header` element. The clearfix essentially prevents the parent element from collapsing upon itself, which means that the bottom margin do not collapse.

You could achieve the exact same thing by simply adding `overflow: hidden` to the element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tj8zhd7z/)

```
#header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try after removing below style?

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: No luck with removing this css reset code:(  the ghost top margin is still there

Comment: @sri The margin isn't from the `body` element. See my answer.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks for detailed explanation.