# Why Chrome add margin to body element?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have simple html document. Is one element  into body. When I set margin-top in div element, Chrome add the same margin to body. 
Margin is visible only developer tools.
My code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">Test</div>

<style>
body { background-color: red; }

#main { background-color: blue; margin-top: 100px; }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742720/104380

Comment: possible related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/2680478/104380

Comment: possible related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33818444/104380

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/26311891/104380

Comment: ...Did you check other browsers before declaring this is a Chrome-related issue?

Answer (score 1):

A HTML web document has default css styles, these values are defaulted if you haven't applied any styles of your own. You can override them by applying styles on those particular elements.

for instance, applying the below style, body tag loses its default css style

```
body{
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following style to body tag.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gv0gsr32/) is the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looking right.(ı tried to change margin block number and it worked)

Any code on the top maybe affect your margin block.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">Test</div>

<style>
body { background-color: red; }

#main { background-color: blue; margin-top: 100px; }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```